# Comparing database result and multidimensionnal array

Tags: php

I have arrays and data from a databse, and need to compare them.

```
$mydays = array( 
    'Monday' => array('10:00','11:00','12:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00'), 
    'Tuesday' => array('10:00','11:00','12:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00'), 
    'Wednesday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00'), 
    'Thursday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00'), 
    'Friday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00'), 
    'Saturday' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00') 
);

$myhours = array( 
    "2017-02-27" => array("17:00"), 
    "2017-03-01" => array("16:00","17:00","18:00"), 
    "2017-03-03" => array("17:00"), 
    "2017-03-08" => array("17:00","18:00"), 
    "2017-03-10" => array("17:00","18:00") 
);
```

From a database, I retrieve some data such as :

```
$thisday = Monday
$thisdate = yyyy-mm-dd
$thishour = H:i

$myday = $mydays[$thisday];

foreach ($myday as $hour) { /* loop through hours for this specific day */

// I need to find out if there is a date/hour from "$myhours" that matches my data
// ie: I have database:Monday -> I loop through the hours from $mydays:Monday
// I then have : 10:00,11:00,12:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,18:00
// from there, I need to know if, in "$myhours", I have the same hour for "$thisdate"

}
```

I have read almost every post here, found and tried using :

```
function in_multiarray($elem, $array, $field)
{
$top = sizeof($array) - 1;
$bottom = 0;
while($bottom <= $top)
{
    if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field])) {
            if(in_multiarray_d($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field]))) {
                return true; } else { return false; }
                } else { return false; }
    $bottom++;
    }
}   
return false;
}

if( !in_multiarray("$thisdate", $myhours, "$hour") ) { echo"good"; } else { echo"not good"; }
```

My problem : I don't get a result every time (even when some day/hour matches), and when I do, it's not for every hour, I miss some days/hours... I thought I would maybe need to reset the array, but had no better result doing it.

Q: is my approach a correct way to work around my problem ? If yes, what am I doing wrong ? if not, what is you best advice, or what shall I do ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question (if so, please clarify), but to me this code does the trick: https://3v4l.org/bDR0t

Comment: should this input `$thisday = 'Monday'; $thisdate = "2017-02-27"; $thishour = '11:00'` return `true` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : yes

Comment: @Bogdan : I will test this and let you know

Comment: @user3801953, ok, I've used the input from my previous comment, as you said, it should return `true`/`good`

Comment: unreal ! I had used "kinda" your piece of code earlier, as part of my tests, and didn't succeed... So many tries around this script that I can't remember where it failed though ^^ But this time it's OK. Thanks, and to @Bogan too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `in_array` function:

```
...
$thisday = 'Monday'; 
$thisdate = "2017-02-27"; 
$thishour = '11:00';

// check if we have a valid weekday name and date/time value
if (isset($mydays[$thisday]) && isset($myhours[$thisdate]) 
    && in_array($thishour, $mydays[$thisday])) {
    echo 'good';
} else {
    echo "not good";
}
```