# pushing results into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I need to go beyond the results of this [question]: [Comparing database result and multidimensionnal array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314729/comparing-database-result-and-multidimensionnal-array/42330199#42330199)

I need to add values to the array.

I look for the key (ie: "2017-03-30"). If key exists, I need to add an hour to the existing array value, associated to the related key/date. To make myself as clear as possible : I have a date + hour such as '2017-03-30' + '11:00'.

I use array key exists and if result is true, I need to push the hour into the sub-array.

```
 '2017-03-30' => array('9:00','10:00','14:00')
 //needs to become
 '2017-03-30' => array('9:00','10:00','14:00','11:00')
 //or
 '2017-03-30' => array('9:00','10:00','11:00','14:00')
```

if result is false, I need to add the date+hour into the array.

```
  array( '2017-03-24' => array('14:00'), '2017-03-29' => array('15:00') )
 //will become :
 array( '2017-03-24' => array('14:00'), '2017-03-29' => array('15:00'), '2017-03-30' => array('11:00') )
```

I searched for a function, but neither array_push nor array_merge will do the job. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried anything ? , If you tried then share your code.

Comment: I tried many little portions of script, nothing that led to something I could publish here. Many errors, I search for the reasons, found no clue, then decided to delete all that stuff and ask for help ^^. that's why there's no code included...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generic function like this, which sadly I don't think exists in PHP's general functions

```
function array_push_sub(&$table, $key, $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $table)) $table[$key][] = $value;
    else $table[$key] = [$value];
}

$myArray = [];
array_push_sub($myArray, "2017-03-21", "09:00");

//Please note that $table[$date][] = $time;
//Is the same as array_push($table[$date], $time);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that helps for the second part of it. $myArray is already declared, so I just modified $myArray = []; I still work on the 1st part, and will let you know...

Comment: I now work on/with this : function array_push_sub(&$table, $key, $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $table)) { $table[$key][] = $value; sort($table[$key]); }
    else { $table[$key] = [$value]; }
}
works fine, and re-orders the array. Only one single problem -> when I have 9:00, it goes at the end and not at the beginning of the array (ty cap'tain obvious ^^) but I'll deal with this... TY for the help

Comment: @user3801953 Try using sort($myArray[$currentDate], SORT_NUMERIC), you may want tu use SORT_NUMERIC as your second parameter because regular sorting will put "9:00" after "11:00" unless you write it "09:00".

Comment: yees :) found SORT_NUMERIC yesterday and was just checking all kind of sorting types, you saved me time ;) upvoted and accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$arrayVariable['wantedKey'] = $insertedArray`, like

```
$startArray = array( '2017-03-24' => array('14:00'), '2017-03-29' => array('15:00') );
$startArray['2017-03-30'] = array('11:00');
```

And that will get You your wanted array.